# Pandas Number of Row Since Condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with dates as the index

```
    col
d1  1
d2  0
d3  5
d4  6
d7  0
```

I want to find all values that are greater than 0 and then replace the value with the number of days (or rows) since the last value that was greater than 0.

So in this case the column would be

```
    col
d1  NaN
d2  0
d3  2
d4  1
d7  0
```

Can anyone see a good way of doing this?

Comment: Why is first value `NaN` ?

Comment: Doesn't have to be but I thought it probably would be because there's no row above it, for it to count from... if that makes sense?

Comment: I other words I need to count the number of 0's ( + 1) between the current row and the last row that isn't a 0

Comment: I realise I'm not explaining this very well / its probably quite hard to do. So apologies for that

Comment: Is possible some consecutive `0` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need count values between `0` with [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
m = df['col'].ne(0)
s = df.groupby(m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum()).cumcount(ascending=False).add(1)
df['new'] = np.where(m, s, 0)
print (df)
    col  new
d1    1    1
d2    0    0
d3    5    2
d4    6    1
d7    0    0
```

And if necessary set `NaN` to values before first `0`:

```
df.iloc[:(~m.values).argmax(), df.columns.get_loc('new')] = np.nan
print (df)
    col  new
d1    1  NaN
d2    0  0.0
d3    5  2.0
d4    6  1.0
d7    0  0.0
```